# Sobre escribir salida de un Enum en Graphene

Tags: python, django, graphql

Estoy trabajando con `graphene` y `graphene-django` y tengo un problema con un campo, que los valores del `choices` sean un número. Al momento de hacer un query, el resultado es "A_1" y debería ser 1 (entero). Por ejemplo:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   score = models.Integer(choices=((1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)))
```

Y haciendo este query:

```
query {
    foo {
       score
    }
}
```

me da este resultado:

```
{
  "data": {
    "foo": {
      "source": "A_1"
    }
  }
}
```

He estado investigando y graphene-django crea un `Enum` con el `choices` y hay una función que valida el nombre del item del `choices`.

```
def convert_choice_name(name):
    name = to_const(force_text(name))
    try:
        assert_valid_name(name)
    except AssertionError:
        name = "A_%s" % name
    return name
```

la función assert_valida_name tiene una expresión regular que valida que inicie con una letra o un '_'

```
r'^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
```

Entonces, la pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo sobreescribir la salida que me da graphene?

Gracias.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no está del todo clara. ¿Quieres sobreescribir `data['foo']['source']` para que sea `1` en lugar de `"A_1"`?, ¿quieres configurar graphene para que devuelva el valor del `choices` en lugar del valor del `Enum`?, ¿otra cosa?

Comment: Sí, sobreescribir para que sea 1 en lugar de "A_1". Gracias

Comment: algo así, `int(data['foo']['source'].split('_')[-1])`, no te valdría?

Comment: no mucho por dos razones:
1) eso se haría cuando ya tenga la respuesta y yo quiero enviar el valor real en la respuesta.
2) busco una mejor forma de hacerlo, o sea, que la librería tenga algo para hacer eso. Hacerlo así sería un poco smell code.

He intentado en el resolve, pero tampoco me ha funcionado.
Gracias de todas formas